# Shapes (circle, arc..) and lines with tkinter canvas not smooth on Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, canvas, tkinter, antialiasing

New to Python 3, I'm using canvas with tkinter trying to draw some basic shapes but unfortunately the results are horrible as you can see bellow. It's not smooth. I think the antialiasing is missing here.
So, please, is there any solution for this problem?

Here is a sample code I use

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.config(width=500, height=500)
coord = 100, 100, 400, 400
canvas.create_arc(coord, start=90, extent=100, fill='red')
canvas.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')

root.mainloop()
```

Thank you.

[Circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJw6v.png)

[Arc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFP3P.png)

Comment: Please post the code you used to draw those shapes.

Comment: Those pictures are just what the raw shapes are when drawn on a canvas (without anti-aliasing). There is nothing wrong with them, thus you can't 'fix' them.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I added the sample code I used.

Comment: You can try by varying the thickness